# Allow Notification without clicking button

Tags: javascript, laravel, notifications

i want to ask about notification

right now i have this notification with "Notify Me" button that return this notification

[Notification allow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmv5p.png)

but i still use this button to trigger the push notification

```
<button onclick="notifyMe()">Notify me!</button>
```

this is the javscript function

```
 function notifyMe() {

           function AutoRefresh( t ) {
               setTimeout("location.reload(true);", t);
            }
        // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
        if (!("Notification" in window)) {
            alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
        }

        // Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
        else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
            // If it's okay let's create a notification
            var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
        }

        // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
        else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
            Notification.requestPermission().then(function (permission) {
            // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
            if (permission === "granted") {
                var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
            }
            });
        }

        }
```

what i want is the notification is automatically showed up without the button to trigger

how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  notifyMe();
});
```

Then, it will trigger the notification automatically.

Comment: where should i put it? in the views?